# Refresh custom template.xml without restarting Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I've created a custom Activity template in Android Studio 3.4.1 ...**/plugins/android/lib/templates/activities** folder (probably not the best location) and noticed that changes to the content files are immediately in effect when I use the template.

When I modify the initial configuration model file of the template (template.xml), instead, the changes are not immediately reflected by the form appearing at new custom activity creation time and I've to restart AS in order to see them appear.

Is there any way to make this kind of modification work without restarting AS?